# JUnit and Cobertura Code Coverage

Tags: java, junit

I am testing two methods using `JUnit` and the problem that I am facing is that the test cases work fine if I run them individually but the second test always fails and throw `RuntimeException` that I am expecting if I run them together. For the second method I am testing the `Null` condition therefore I am expecting `RuntimeException` and for the first method I am testing the second `if` block which takes a `boolean` and I am setting it. So far `Line Coverage` is 81% and `Branch Coverage` is 66% but I am not sure what I am doing wrong on my test cases due to which I am not getting full line and branch coverage.

Class under test:

```
private static ObjectMapper mapper;

public static ObjectMapper initialize( ClientConfiguration config ) {       
    if( mapper == null ) {
        synchronized (ObjectMapperHolder.class) {
            mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY,true);

            //Allows Users to overwrite the Jackson Behavior of failing when they encounter an unknown property in the response
            if( config.isJsonIgnoreUnknownProperties() ) {
                mapper.configure( DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false );
            }
        }
    }
    return mapper;
}

public static ObjectMapper getInstance() {
    if( mapper == null ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( "The initialize() method must be called before the ObjectMapper can be used" );
    }
    return mapper;
}
```

JUnits:

```
@Test
public void testInitialize() throws Exception { 
    ClientConfiguration configuration = new ClientConfiguration();
    configuration.setJsonIgnoreUnknownProperties(true);

    ObjectMapperHolder.initialize(configuration);

    assertNotNull(configuration);
}

@Test(expected=RuntimeException.class)
public void testGetInstance() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapperHolder.getInstance();
}
```

Comment: Do you know specifically which lines are not covered? There should be a report file with this information as part of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each test should be independent. If you can't remove the static state (ie, the static field `mapper`), then you probably should add a `@Before @After` method which reset this field.

For the coverage:

- `getInstance` has two branches : If mapper is null or not null. You are only testing one branch
- `initialize` has 3 states : `mapper == null && isJsonIgnoreUnknownProperties == true`, `mapper == null && isJsonIgnoreUnknownProperties == false`, `mapper != null`. You are testing only one branch.

Moreover, your `assertNotNull(configuration)` is unnecessary. You should probably test that `initialize` return a mapper not null.

Comment: @Jeremine, thank you for reminding me about the static variable. I was dealing like an instance variable forgetting about the fact that there is only one mapper. Yo are correct, so far I don't have all the branches covered but I will. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jeremine. I reassigned the static variable a new value through reflection  and it worked. I know this is not the best idea to use reflection but I guess I have no other option.

Comment: @Yousuf yes, that's why a static state should be avoided if possible, as it's not testable. If you can't remove this static field (and use for example a DI framework) and can't add a static protected method to reset this field, you don't have another choice of using reflection to reset this field.